# jQuery validate Uncaught TypeError Cannot read property 'form' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jquery validate http://jqueryvalidation.org/

I have a form with a first field added manually (hard coded)

Then adding more fields is done programatically. The ARE appended inside the form tags already, into a div #to-append

The one added manually validates fine.

For the rest, I am trying to add the rules like this, every time i add a field:

```
var $largestID = $("#to-append > div:last > div:first > input:first").attr("id");
console.log($largestID); //throws right id

$($largestID).rules("add", {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        pattern: yt

});
```

But get the  "Uncaught TypeError Cannot read property 'form' of undefined" error stated above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The rules should be added to the DOM elements or the tags. You are adding to ID.

Comment: What is the place of this js code in your script, before form or after form?

Comment: @Sravan I tried with name it still doesn't work

Comment: @ PHPExpert I am including it at the end before the </body>

Comment: @Sravan I get a different error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: url[] . My names are an array, how can i do it then?

Comment: I have updated my answer.please check

Answer (score 4):

You are adding rule taking ID string. Instead take the element selector, and add rule to that selector.

```js
var $largestID = $("#to-append > div:last > div:first > input:first").attr("id");
console.log($largestID); //throws right id

$('#'+$largestID).each(function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
       required: true,
       minlength: 3,
       pattern: yt
    });
});
```

Use the `$('#'+$largestID)` to get the field of that ID, and then add rules.

To add rules to array, use:

```
 $('#'+$largestID).each(function () { })
```

you can even validate the array of names of that element:

```js
 $('#'+$largestID).validate({
    rules: {
      'url[]': {
        required: true,
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the error has gone away but it still ignores the rules. I think i have to add them to the name as Sravan said. How would i go about if the names are an array (name="url[]").

Comment: Hai, I updated my answer and added a loop for your array. Please check

Comment: I am adding them one by one, i dont need to trasverse the array, the thing was if a name like url[] could or not cause any problems. Anyways, what Bramar proposed, which is indistictive of names or ids, does not work either. Nor does adding required="required" or required="true".

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use the ID. You have a selector that returns the element, add the rule to that directly.

```
$("#to-append > div:last > div:first > input:first").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    minlength: 3,
    pattern: yt

});
```

Comment: Nothing seems to work, this is logical and should, but even if i get no jquery errors, the form doesn't submit. I get no validation messages whatsoever either, it just doesn't sumbit. Maybe I have an error somewhere else

Comment: I had ignore:[] in my validate function at the beginning thinking that was to ignore the brackets, It was not. Now that i removed that line, the validation works, the message show, but the form gets submitted regardless of errors. Thanks